Making a Mongoose schema type dependant on an earlier value
I'm working on a project that has a document that will need to have different information depending on the type of the document. A simplfied example might be like this:
const blueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    typeOfBlue: {
        type: String,
        enum: [`Ocean`, `Sky`]
    }
})

const redSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    typeOfRed: {
        type: String,
        enum: [`Wine`, `Blood`]
    }
})

const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    colour: 
    {
        type: String,
        enum: [`Blue`, `Red`],
        required: true
    },
    colourInformation: //This should be redSchema || blueSchema depending on the value of colour
})


The problem is that I'm unable to reference the value of the document before it's initialised so I can't figure out how to word any function or such so that it would not result in an undefined result.
Mostly I've tried things like the bellow but as I mentioned, it usually results in an undefined output or else mongoose can't access the value before it's saved.
function validateColour(colour) {
    if (colour === `Blue`) {
        return blueSchema
    } else if (colour === `Red`) {
        return redSchema
    }
}

const blueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    typeOfBlue: {
        type: String,
        enum: [`Ocean`, `Sky`]
    }
})

const redSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    typeOfRed: {
        type: String,
        enum: [`Wine`, `Blood`]
    }
})

const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    colour: 
    {
        type: String,
        enum: [`Blue`, `Red`],
        required: true
    },
    colourInformation: validateColour(this.colour)
})

